# Replace part of line with different text from another file line by line

Tags: ubuntu, awk, sed

Im trying to solve the problem with that, but i can just replace the whole string instead of just part

That's what i have so far:

```
cat mock.txt | sed -i -e '/mock/{R/dev/stdin' -e 'd;}' test{1..500}.txt
```

I want to replace the part of lines matching a pattern from the lines in order from another file, i have up to 500 txt files, with structure: 
**test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt...**

```
11111
22222
333= mock 33
55555
77777
```

and so im reading file one by one and to replace in first test1.txt file mock pattern with first line from mock.txt file, in second test2.txt replace the mock pattern line with second line from mock.txt file, which has structure like:
**mock.txt**

```
randomText1
randomText2
randomText3
randomText4
randomText5
```

and so on till the last .txt file in folder

Comment: 1 clarification, is it only 1 line in each text files will have `mock` string or there can be more please let us know?

Comment: it could have a lot

Comment: Ok, so every next file you need the first mock string occurence to be replaced with 1st value of mock file? Or it should continue its count from last file?

Comment: for instance each test{n}.txt file has some mock occurrence either one or multiple, so all mock patterns in first file should be replace with first line in mock.txt, and so on

Comment: Could you ;please try my EDIT solution and let me know, try it on 1 or 2 files once(test files) and see how it goes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about previous error, please try below again.
With GNU awk v4.1.0+ (please backup your files first):

```
awk -i inplace 'NR==FNR{re[FNR]=$0;print;next}match(FILENAME,/test([0-9]+)/, fi){gsub("mock",re[fi[1]])}1' mock.txt test{1..500}.txt
```

Note the files cannot have carriage returns `\r\n` endings, if they have, please comment.

If the files contain many lines, then to be efficient and to put it in several lines for readability:

```
awk -i inplace '
    NR==FNR{re[FNR]=$0;print;next}
    FNR==1{match(FILENAME,/test([0-9]+)/, fi)}
    /mock/{gsub(/mock/,re[fi[1]])}
    1' mock.txt test{1..500}.txt
```

Comment: and if i want to change all occurrence of mock with current position + 2 or whatever different from current position from mock.txt, would the code change a lot? Like with text1.txt we would change mock to randomText3, with text2.txt -> randomText5 and so on

Comment: @Pursentiy Given `mock.txt` has redundent lines, change the first `re[FNR]` to `re[FNR-2]` ***OR*** last `re[fi[1]]` to `re[fi[1]+2]` would do.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '/mock/R mockFile' -e '//d' file ...
```

N.B. The mock file is named within the sed script rather than as input via stdin. This allows sed to reset the mockFile for each input file.

This will replace all instances of `mock` by a line from the mock file sequentially. However if you want to link all instances of mock in each file to its position within the mock file i.e. all instances of mock in file1 to line 1 of the mock file etc, use:

```
parallel sed -i '/mock/c\{1}' {2} :::: mockFile :::+ file{1..500}.txt
```

Comment: It erases all lines from mock.txt and all the test{n}.txt files were left the same, Awk 4.1.4.

Comment: @Pursentiy This is a sed solution not an awk and the mock file is read only, perhaps you might show your work to clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think @Pursentiy was commenting to my answer, which I found out was faulty so I deleted temporarily.

Comment: @potong the question has been solved, thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Since OP is saying each time for file replacement should start from very first occurence of mock string from mock file so posting following now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$0
  next
}
prev!=FILENAME{
  if(prev){
    close("temp")
    system("mv  temp " prev)
  }
}
FNR==1{
  prev=FILENAME
  count=""
}
/mock/{
  $0=a[++count]
}
{
  print > "temp"
}
END{
  if(prev){
    close("temp")
    system("mv  temp " prev)
  }
}' mock.txt test[0-9].txt
```

---

---

Could you please try following. In shost explanation(will add full explanation) this will change string mock value as per mock.text file's value. I have added a comment to ask OP about if a file can have more than 1 occurence of it, will update it as per OP's answer too.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$0
  next
}
prev!=FILENAME{
  if(prev){
    close("temp")
    system("mv  temp " prev)
  }
}
FNR==1{
  prev=FILENAME
}
/mock/{
  $0=a[++count]
}
{
  print > "temp"
}
END{
  if(prev){
    close("temp")
    system("mv  temp " prev)
  }
}' mock.txt test[0-9].txt
```

Comment: @Pursentiy, please try my EDIT solution now and let me know? Also I would suggest try this with 2 or 3 fiels once looking good then only run for all text files.

Comment: @Pursentiy, cool, give it sometime and when you see many answers please select anyone of them as correct answer out of all, happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

## You can't do this by using `sed` in one step.

From `info sed`

> ```
> 'R filename'
>      Queue a line of FILENAME to be read and inserted into the output
>      stream at the end of the current cycle, or when the next input line
>      is read.
> ```

So for doing this, you have to make a *second pass*:

```
cd /tmp
seq -f first-%03g 1 20 | tee test-{1..30}.txt >/dev/null 
seq -f newline-%04g 44 244 | sed -i -e '/first-004/R/dev/stdin' test-{1..30}.txt
sed -e '/first-004/{N;s/^\(.*\)rst-00\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/}' -i test-{1..30}.txt
```

Then

```
head -6 test-6.txt
first-001
first-002
first-003
finewline-00494
first-005
first-006
```

Where `rst-00` is replaced by `newline-0049` on line where originally was `first-004`.

## From there, matching your request, but not tested:

there are two pass:

```
sed -e '/mock/R/dev/stdin' -i test{1..500}.txt <mock.txt
sed -e '/mock/{N;s/^\(.*\)mock\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\1\3\2/}' -i test{1..500}.txt
```

Comment: Hmmm... Seem correct now, just test last two lines of this post.